# Changing .css overflow at the beginning and end of click function

Tags: jquery, overflow

In Jquery I'm trying to have ("html, body") overflowY change at the start of a click function and change again at the end -- from hidden to visible. A div within the function animates to move up the html page and the browser adds the scroll bar while it's animating and removes it when it's done, giving the appearance that the div isn't moving up in a straight line. This is why I need to add a "overflow: hidden" during the beginning of the click event. It needs to go back to visible when other elements on html page are clicked and content expands the height of the window.

Is this possible in Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

See http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/ and http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work. The scroll bar still appears during the animation. I added:                    $("#start").mouseup(function() {
  $("html, body").css("overflowY, hidden");
 }).mousedown(function() {
  $("html, body").css("overflowY, visible");
 });